# Spring UnsatisfiedDependencyException and Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object

Tags: spring, java

I want to create a generic repository class for two domain objects:
Product and Category and be able to list all elements in index.html.

Here's my code:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

private final ProdCatService<Category> categoryProdCatService;

public IndexController(ProdCatService<Category> categoryProdCatService) {
    this.categoryProdCatService = categoryProdCatService;
}

@RequestMapping({"","/","index"})
public String getIndexPage(Model model)
{       
    model.addAttribute("cat", categoryProdCatService.getAll());
    return "index";
}
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProdCatRepository<T> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> { }
```

Service:

```
public interface ProdCatService<T> {

Set<T> getAll();
T findById(Long id);
}


@Service
public class ProdCatServiceImpl<T> implements ProdCatService {

private final ProdCatRepository<T> prodCatRepository;

public ProdCatServiceImpl(ProdCatRepository<T> prodCatRepository) {
    this.prodCatRepository = prodCatRepository;
}

@Override
public Set<T> getAll() {
    Set<T> productsSet = new HashSet<>();
    prodCatRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(productsSet::add);
    return productsSet;
}

@Override
public T findById(Long id) {
    return prodCatRepository.findById(id).get();
}
}
```

So the problem is I get banch of errors like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController' defined in file [C:\Users\Michał\Documents\webstore-v-1\target\classes\info\mike\webstorev1\controllers\IndexController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'prodCatServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Michał\Documents\webstore-v-1\target\classes\info\mike\webstorev1\service\ProdCatServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prodCatRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

and

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prodCatRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

I am asking for help. I looked through a S/O, but couldn't find an answer.

Edit for Category domain class.

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String categoryName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private Set<Product> products;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Category other = (Category) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Start by removing the `final` modifier from those service/repository attribute.

Comment: where is your bean definition, as per error, it seems correct parameters have not passed while creating the bean

Comment: final removed, still getting error

Comment: user2044822, which bean ?

Comment: Category bean .

Comment: I added a Category domain class

Comment: Ok the problem here appears to be in Identifying Category but spring is identifying it just as object instead of entity category.

Comment: Is any way to change this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a generic repository class for two domain objects:
>   Product and Category and be able to list all elements in index.html.

Your requirement makes no sense.
To achieve it you should define a base class between Product and Category and specify this base class in the generic repository.
A Category is a concept different from a Product.
So but by twisting the hierarchy, you will not manage to define this base class.
And even if you defined it, it will not reflect fields required both in Category and Product.
So how do you want to list correctly them in the client side in these conditions ?

Then, why do you want to reinvent the wheel ?
Actually you use Spring Data to reduce boiler plate code :

```
public interface ProdCatRepository<T> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> { }
```

It is clearly enough and easy to declare.
Don't try to be too clever by associating things that should not be and define a distinct repository for each one :

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> { }
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> { }
```

Comment: In last line you mean public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> { } ?

Comment: Ok, so if you suggest this is a better and cleaner option than making generic I finish this your way.

Comment: @janusz if generic is not better, then why it is created?!